# Is there a word or phrase when there occurs two sad events in tandem

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, idioms

Is there a word or phrase when there occurs two sad/traumatic  events in tandem; Like Double whammy is when two-fold blow or setback. But I think i cannot use double whammy. Like in this example:

Jill's father died in the month of June this year. And now i am hearing this news that his cousin sister passed away yesterday. That a ________ (double whammy)

Comment: You should really split this into two separate questions.

Comment: @alwayslearning I know this would be a comment, but i had two contrasting context to explain in one question.

Comment: Well, that would still be OK if you are looking for a single answer to both your questions. It doesn't look like it currently; perhaps you should edit it.

Answer (score 2):

A phrase which describes that scenario is :

**When it rains it pours**

> used to say that when something bad happens other bad things usually happen at the same time

[Link to definition from Merrian-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when%20it%20rains,%20it%20pours)